# Can not Display Service in Service List

Tags: linux, rhel, services

There is service named filebeat. It works on oracle linux 6.8 machine,

```
chkconfig --list
```

it does not show but when run this command

```
ps -ef | grep filebeat
```

ps -ef | grep filebeat
root      2583 18280  0 10:10 pts/7    00:00:00 grep filebeat
root     14456     1  0 Mar27 ?        00:00:00 /usr/share/filebeat/bin/filebeat-god -r / -n -p /var/run/filebeat.pid --

/usr/share/filebeat/bin/filebeat -c /etc/filebeat/filebeat.yml -path.home /usr/share/filebeat -path.config /etc/filebeat -path.data /var/lib/filebeat -path.logs /var/log/filebeat

root     14457 14456  2 Mar27 ?        16:41:54 /usr/share/filebeat/bin/filebeat -c /etc/filebeat/filebeat.yml -path.home /usr/share/filebeat -path.config /etc/filebeat -path.data /var/lib/filebeat -path.logs /var/log/filebeat

I can see that the service is working and I also could not find in /etc/init.d

And I checked the log file it writes into log file.

`lsof filebeat` returns;

`COMMAND    PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF   NODE NAME`

`filebeat 14457 root    2w   REG  252,1  8995935 529475 filebeat`

and

```
  ps p 14457

  PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND

  14457 ?        Sl   1001:57 /usr/share/filebeat/bin/filebeat -c 

  /etc/filebeat/filebeat.yml -path.home /usr/share/filebeat -path.config 

  /etc/filebeat -path.data /var/lib/filebeat -path.logs /var/log/fileb
```

how can I find where is the location of filebeat service file in order to start or stop?

Comment: systemd command works on redhat 7 OS not for redhat 6.8 OS

Comment: My oversight... Could it be installed manually then?

Comment: No it can not be,it designed for RHEL 7.

Comment: Use the lsof command ti dicipher the process writing to the log file and work your way back from there.

Comment: `lsof filebeat` command returns;
filebeat 14457 root    2w   REG  252,1  8995935 529475 filebeat `ps p 14457`  14457 ?        Sl   1001:57 /usr/share/filebeat/bin/filebeat -c /etc/filebeat/filebeat.yml -path.home /usr/share/filebeat -path.config /etc/filebeat -path.data /var/lib/filebeat -path.logs  but I am still not able start or stop service. I have already known that the service is working but the problem is not to find service binary in order to start or stop

Answer (score 0):

If it's a port-based service, you can use netstat.

```
netstat -tulpn | grep filebeat
```